# Class Diagram Challenge search for help in making a design

Tags: design-patterns, class-diagram

I have a chalange in class diagram that I cant resolve:

There is a stock market, clients and brokers.

the client ask to buy/sell shares from his broker.

the broker need to get notification when the price is good to buy/sell share.

I know its a little bit abstract but its what I know from a job intreview soo if you think to add class I think its good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion would be to look at the Observer pattern.  It sounds like the Broker will observe the Market (Market tells Broker when to buy/sell) and the Client will observe the Broker in a similar fashion.

So you would have some StockObserver interface with buy and sell methods.  Client and Broker would implement them and do whatever they need to when they are notified.

Here's a link if you need one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: This is the answer your instructor is looking for. If you are interested in the general programming model, check out event-driven programming.

Comment: and event driven programming deals with events/listeners where one object listens to another waiting for an event to fire, which is exactly how the Observer pattern behaves